# How to change default values for calling CRTMNU from sda

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm using SDA (Screen Design Agent) in Green Screen to create menus. My Projects have their own library and I learned that I can add `CURLIB(*MNULIB)` to the call to CRTMNU from within SDA, so when starting programs from menus, the current library will be changed and programs find their data files.

I want to have set `CURLIB(*MNULIB)` as default. Setting this parameter via `CHGCMDDFT` apparently doesn't affect the defaults from within SDA.

Does anyone know how to change call values from within SDA? Maybe edit some table by hand?